# iptables rules to rate-limit ICMP(Ping) traffic to 5 packets per second

Tags: iptables

**Problem** -Trying to figure out the IPTABLES rule for above mentioned requirment.

**Requirements**-
Can anyone please advise me here how to achieve it.

I was trying this but not successful -

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 5/second -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a policy to drop packets unless explicit rule or you have a drop rule at the end...

**sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT --match limit --limit 30/minute**

will limit the specific echo-request icmp messages (ping) allowed per minute

David Howard

**Here's an example iptable (INPUT chain):**

sudo iptables -L INPUT

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh

ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request limit: avg 30/min burst 5

DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

**And don't forget IPv6!**

**sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type echo-request -j ACCEPT --match limit --limit 30/minute**